# JavaScript: BigInteger implementation of a geometric sum

Tags: javascript

Say I have this equation here:

```
a * (1 - r ^ n) / (1 - r)
```

Basically, it is the formula for the sum of a geometric sequence. In our case, `r` is a decimal (float).

I am expecting the resulting number to be greater than the maximum safe integer, so BigInt will have to be used.

Is there a BigInt implementation of the Geometric Sum?

Thanks in advance!

This is what I have tried:

```js
function geoSum(a, r, n) {
  return BigInt(a * ((1 - r ** n) / (1 - n)));
}
```

Which already becomes `Infinity` before it can be converted into a BigInt.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you should take into consideration the value of r , before applying the formula

Comment: hello, what do you mean taking into consideration the value of r?

Comment: I meant r!=1 , but i think it is not as you said in question . Could you please share values of a , r and n? Also we do have BigInt in js https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt

Comment: `geoSum = (a, r, n) =>  a* ((1n - r ** n) / (1n - n)); geoSum(2n, 2n, 2n)`  1n is shorthand for BigInt(1).  It would make more sense to require parameter input to already be in BigInt form or add type assertions, rather than converting them on the fly, since the caller should and needs to know that they will receive a BigInt and that they have to handle it.  TL;DR BigInt conversion should be on the onus of the caller.  You can make it handle both numbers and BigInt too, but it should be the responsibility of the caller to use geoSum(BigInt) correctly.  *Caller knows if numbers are big.*

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your comments! I will now mark the correct answer. Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should convert each of the parameters to `BigInt` *before* applying the operations:

```js
function geoSum(a, r, n) {
  const an = BigInt(a);
  const rn = BigInt(r);
  const nn = BigInt(n);

  return an * ((1n - rn ** nn) / (1n - nn));
}

const result = geoSum(150, 151, 152);

console.log(String(result));
console.log(Number(result));
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your answer! I will test it out now :)

Answer (score 0):

I just wrapped everything with `BigInt`.

```
function geoSum(a, r, n) {
  return BigInt(BigInt(a) * (BigInt(BigInt(1) - BigInt(BigInt(r) ** BigInt(n))) /
         BigInt(BigInt(1) - BigInt(n))));
}
```

```
geoSum(2,5,10)
```

returned:

```
2170138n
```

I don't know if the result makes sense to you.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the answer! I will test it out now :)